# Socket.io communication between server and client - not receveing messages from client

Tags: node.js, sockets, server, client, io-socket

I have an application server and client with socket.io, and I'm trying to have a communication between them. Unfortunetely it's not working as expected.
In general the process is like.

1 - Initiate server.
2 - Initiate client
3 - Connect client in the server
4 - server receive the message that connect and send a broadcast to client.
5 - client receive message and send back "hello" message and present in the console

step 4 and 5 not working at all. any help?

Codes:

SERVER -----------------------------------------------

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected')
  io.emit('broadcast msg from server')


   io.on('hello', () => {
    console.log('mensagem do client')
    io.emit('hello');
    });

});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
 
});
```

//Client -----------------------------------------------

```
const ioClient = io.connect("http://localhost:3000")
const readline = require('readline')

ioClient.on("connect", () => {
    console.log('conectou')
});

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,   
    utput: process.stdout
});

ioClient.on("broadcast msg from server", () => {
    console.log("broadcast msg from server");

    ioClient.emit("hello");
    
});

ioClient.on("hello", () => {
    console.log("helloFrom server");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing out on the client-side `socket.io-client` as the server-side `socket.io` will not work on the client side. You'll need to install it first before establishing the connection to the server side.

```
$ npm install socket.io-client
```

After installing the above, you will have to insert the following line before the first line of `Client`.

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems in the code you post:

1. You don't show importing the Express module on the server
2. You don't show importing the socket.io-client module in the client
3. You code for listening for the "hello" message on the server is wrong.

When I run this exact code (filling in some modules you don't show code to load):

Server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected')
    io.emit('broadcast msg from server')


    io.on('hello', () => {
        console.log('mensagem do client')
        io.emit('hello');
    });

});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');

});
```

Client:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const ioClient = io.connect("http://localhost:3000")

ioClient.on("connect", () => {
    console.log('conectou')
});

ioClient.on("broadcast msg from server", () => {
    console.log("broadcast msg from server");

    ioClient.emit("hello");

});

ioClient.on("hello", () => {
    console.log("helloFrom server");
});
```

I get this output in the client console:

```
conectou
broadcast msg from server
```

And this output in the server console:

```
listening on *:3000
a user connected
```

So, it appears that the client is indeed getting a message.  So, apparently something is different in your actual code than what I'm running here if your client isn't getting that message.  **The main thing you don't show in your code is this in the client:**

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
```

**and this in the server:**

```
const express = require('express');
```

**Note also that this part of your code is wrong:**

```
io.on('hello', () => {
    console.log('mensagem do client')
    io.emit('hello');
});
```

On the server messages arrive to a socket, not to `io`.  `io` events are for connection mechanics only.

So, on your server, this should be:

```
socket.on('hello', () => {
    console.log('mensagem do client')
    io.emit('hello');
});
```

After making that additional fix, the client console shows:

```
conectou
broadcast msg from server
helloFrom server
```

And the server console shows:

```
listening on *:3000
a user connected
mensagem do client
```